# How I can Bootstrap data table filter with php foreach

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap-4

Table 1 and 2 picture it work only table 1 data filter:
[image: Table 1 and 2 picture it work only table 1 data filter]
I want to short data after click on table title when I try with while loop SQL data result can filter the data. If I try on PHP function foreach data table can't filter and I unable to click on edit and delete buttom...
Code For table 1 I use like this

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <th>Courses ID</th>
              <th>Photo</th>
              <th>Name</th>                  
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <?php 
              include 'dbconn/conn.php';
              $sql = "SELECT *, students.id AS id FROM students LEFT JOIN position ON position.id=students.course_id LEFT JOIN schedules ON schedules.id=students.schedule_id";
                $query = $conn->query($sql);
                while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
                  ?>
                    <tr>
                      <td><?php echo $row['cardid']; ?></td>
                      <td><img src="<?php echo (!empty($row['photo']))? 'images/'.$row['photo']:'./images/profile.jpg'; ?>" width="30px" height="30px"> <a href="#edit_photo" data-toggle="modal" class="pull-right photo" data-id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span></a></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['firstname'].' '.$row['lastname']; ?></td>                          
                    </tr>
                  <?php
                }
              ?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Code for second table that data pull from function but filter icon didn't show

```
<table id="example2" class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <th>Students ID</th>
              <th>Photo</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Course</th>
              <th>Semester</th>
              <th>Admittion On</th>
              <th>Update</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
             <?php             
              $cust_list = $dbquery->studentinfo();
              foreach($cust_list as $custDetails){
                echo '
                <tr>
                      <td>'.$custDetails['cardid'].'</td>
                      <td><img src="images/'.$custDetails['photo'].'" width="30px" height="30px"> <a href="#edit_photo" data-toggle="modal" class="pull-right photo" data-id="'.$custDetails['id'].'"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span></a></td>
                      <td>'.$custDetails['firstname'].' '.$custDetails['lastname'].'</td>
                      <td>'.$custDetails['description'].'</td>                          
                      <td>'.date('M d, Y', strtotime($custDetails['created_on'])).'</td>
                      <td>
                        <a href="#edit" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-success btn-sm edit btn-flat" data-id="'.$custDetails['id'].'">
                        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</button></a>
                        <a href="#delete" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete btn-flat" data-id="'.$custDetails['id'].'">
                       <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</button></a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                ';
              }       
             ?>    
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Comment: are you trying to actually use datatables?

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

<table id="table_id" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#table_id').dataTable();
    } );
</script>
```

More Info -> https://datatables.net/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).